# How to make tcolorbox theorems without numbering

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox, theorems

I want a box created by `tcolorbox` to make a theorem without numbering. This is my code while setting up:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
```

I've searched online and one tip that I got is using * when making a theorem, so it looks like this:

```
\begin{theorem*}{Theorem Name}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem*}
```

However, although the numbering is gone, there is still a colon (:) and a space. How do I get rid of it?[image]
Also, what are other avilable colors of tcolorbox? **(solved)**

There is also a weird indent after the theorem ends, is there a way to systematically fix that?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem*}{Theorem Name}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem*}
\textit{proof.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide MWE, which demonstrate your problem. In `tcolorbox` ara available all colors defined by `xcolor` package.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, what is MWE?

Comment: Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which has in its preamble loaded only to your problem related packages and defined commands/environments. So, it can be compiled as it is (and by this reproduce your problem in our computers)

Comment: @Zarko Alright. I've put it in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
From your comment follows, that you not need specialized `theorem` box as defined in the `theorems` library, but ordinary box (see third example in MWE below).

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcolorbox{my theorem}[1]{
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, title={#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{theorem}{Theorem Name}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}{Theorem Name}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem*}


\begin{my theorem}{Theorem name}
This is a theorem.
\end{my theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have other colors, than you only need to select desired colors in theorems definitions. For example:

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}
{colback=yellow!30,colframe=orange!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
```

gives

[image]

**Addendum:**

In cases, when you like to have no indented text after `mytherem` box, you need to do the following:

- define `my therem` as

```
\newtcolorbox{my theorem}[1]{%
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, title={#1},
after=\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend\ignorespaces}
```

- between box and text had not to be empty line

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{my theorem}[1]{%
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, title={#1},
after=\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{lipsum}
                          
\begin{document}

\begin{my theorem}{Theorem name}
This is a theorem.
\end{my theorem}
\lipsum*[66]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: \noindent\ignorespacesafterend\ignorespaces]

Comment: I don't want the numbering at all. I just want **Theorem Name** without the leading **My Theorem 1.1:** nor **My Theorem:**

Comment: @CELLSecret, sorry, in your question is stated, that you like to have theorems without numbering. This is solved in answer.

Comment: so I have to ask a new question-? How should I describe it then

Comment: No, it is not needed. I will edit my answer ASAP.

Comment: Alright. Thanks

Comment: Yes! Thanks :) (accepted)

Also, is there a way to systematically prevent indent after theorem?

Comment: @CELLSecret, yes it is. ** (i)** at end of `my theorem` definition add `\noindent\ignorespacesafterend\ignorespaces`, and **(ii)** between box and text after box had not be blank line. See addendum to answer.

Comment: Thanks :) I got it to work